# Composite Pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, composite

I have a question regarding composite pattern.

Does the base class "Component" act like a pointer to point leaf object in "Composite" class?

**Edit:**
Let me ask my question in following words.
**"What is the relation between Composite and Component class?"**

Here is the uml class diagram of the pattern.

[image]

Comment: What I mean to say pointer is that references.

Comment: amit: It is crystal clear. You can also see diagram, and look at diamond symbol.

Comment: It is not homework. It is question, which comes into my mind.

Comment: why it is voted for close. It is clear. Someone is misusing the power of voting.

Comment: Perhaps if you expanded on your question a bit...

Comment: is my question still ambiguous?
I am interested in the bold area of my question. I also believe that diagram will also help us to finding the answer.
 Let me know what else you people need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relation between composite and component:

1) Leaf and Composite usually implement one interface or one abstract class. In your diagram they extend Component. So, the relation on your diagram is **inheritance**.

2) Composite contains instances of Component. Component, as it occasionally can be Composite, can also contain instances of Component. This is called *recursive composition*. In general, the relation is called **aggregation**.

Comment: Indeed, it is aggregation relation.

Comment: @Syed: not quite, as I mention there are 2 kind of relations between Component and Composite: inheritance and aggregation. Combining both these relations gives us a structure which is called *recursive composition* in oop theory.

Answer (score 1):

**Component**

- is the abstraction for all components, including composite ones
- declares the interface for objects in the composition
- (optional) defines an interface for accessing a component's parent in the recursive structure, and implements it if that's appropriate

**Leaf**

- represents leaf objects in the composition
- implements all Component methods

**Composite**

- represents a composite Component (component having children)
- implements methods to manipulate children
- implements all Component methods, generally by delegating them to its children

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: My question is regarding the relation between composite and component.
As you can see diamond shape symbol with composite class.

Answer (score 0):

All container and containee classes declare an “is a” relationship to the interface(*Component*).

All container classes declare a one-to-many “has a” relationship to the interface.

More [here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite)