# Aggregation and Inheritance from the same class?

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

What is the best practise if I have "is a" and "has a" relationships  both in the same time as in figure below

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434085/composite-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of relationships where is-a and has-a both exist together are mostly self-referential relationships.

Classic example of such a relationship is employee to manager. Manager is an employee and Manager has many employees reporting to him.

So, the best practice is to make a foreign-key point to the same table. To elaborate - if we take the same example as employee-manager as I told above, then employee table will have a column 'manager' which is nothing but a foreign key to employee table itself.